# Spectral decomposition of a product of two matrices when one matrix is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

In [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140316/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-sum-of-a-kronecker-product-and-a-diagonal-matrix) it states that when we have two symmetric and positive definite matrices, say $A$ and $B$, where $B$ is a diagonal matrix, the spectral decomposition of $AB$ can be easily computed if the spectral decomposition of $A$ is known.

What's the relationship used here to support this claim?

Comment: Doesn't seem right to me. And it doesn't seem like $B$ being diagonal matters at all. You could always move to its eigenbasis - say $A=UDU^*$ and $B=VEV^*$, with both $E$ and $D$ diagonal, and both $U$ and $V$ unitary, then you could consider the pair of matrices $A'=V^*UDU^*V$ and $B'=E$ being diagonal, and they have the same eigenvalues as the originals and so does their product. And generally knowing the spectrum of two pos-def matrices tells us nothing of the spectrum of their product  so the claim seems wrong.